# Text based on time of day

Tags: javascript

Hi i got this code to show a different message based on the time of the day but it only shows the message after 0. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

JS

```
    var today = new Date();
    var time = today.getHours();
    var greet;


    if (time > 0) {
    greet = 'text 1';
    } else if (time > 12) {
    greet = 'Good afternoon Sir!';
    } else if (time > 18) {
    greet = 'Good evening babe!';
    } else {
    greet = 'yo shits broken yo!';
    }


    var show = document.getElementById('message');
    show.textContent = greet;
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Productiviteits website voor eigen gebruik :) ">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="Jeroen Renema">

    <!-- Title -->

    <title>Productivity Library</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 id="message">hey</h2>
    <script src="js/Welcome.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: pretty much every hour is > 0, so that's the condition you'll meet all the time with the exception of midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the order of your `if`. The first matching condition will be executed. And `> 0` will be matched even if the value is `> 12` or `> 18`. So just change the order. ;)

And I would suggest to change the last check to `time >= 0`, because if someone will access this page just after midnight, the text `yo shits broken yo!` will be displayed until it's `1 o'clock`.

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;

if (time > 18) {
  greet = 'Good evening babe!';
} else if (time > 12) {
  greet = 'Good afternoon Sir!';
} else if (time >= 0) {
  greet = 'text 1';
} else {
  greet = 'yo shits broken yo!';
}

var show = document.getElementById('message');
show.textContent = greet;
```

```html
<h2 id="message">hey</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison should also include the `&&` on the value of the below condition to make it work correctly. Currently `time > 0` is always `true` no matter what the value of `time`, it just need to be greater than `0` so to make that work, add `and` condition too.

```js
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours();
var greet;


if (time > 0 && time <= 12) {
  greet = 'text 1';
} else if (time > 12 && time <= 18) {
  greet = 'Good afternoon Sir!';
} else if (time > 18 && time <= 24) {
  greet = 'Good evening babe!';
} else {
  greet = 'yo shits broken yo!';
}


var show = document.getElementById('message');
show.textContent = greet;
```

```html
<h2 id="message">hey</h2>
```